# Is there a way to inject dependency in code using interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I want to get the reference to some Stateless bean inside my code. The problem is I only know the Interface it is implementing (i do not know the name, classname or any other).

Normally for any other EJB i would use @EJB annotation with an Interface

```
private @EJB MyInt myInt;
```

Do anyone know if it is possible to get it via code like for ex:

```
MyInt myInt = new InitialContext().lookuup(MyInt.class);
```

?

Comment: Why don't you just try and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the case where you have multiple implementations for the same interface, you need to specify which implementation you want. Thus, you will need the implementation's mapped name or you will need the JNDI name in order to look it up like that. Your Application Server administrator should be able to provide the JNDI name for you.

If you are going to want to swap out implementations at runtime then you cannot use injection. You will have to do a JNDI lookup.
We built a little factory to lookup a stateless session bean by getting the JNDI name from a configuration table in our database. This enables you to swap out implementations by changing the JNDI name in the database table.
Here is an example of our bean lookup method:

```
public static Object getBean(String jndiName) throws NamingException {
    Object bean = null;
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    bean = ctx.lookup(jndiName);
    return bean;
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing that you want to lookup a remote EJB since you don't know the concrete class name. The remote EJBs are registered in the RMI registry (consider a `map <JndiName, RemoteObject>`). Even if the service provider don't specify a JNDI name for the remote service, the application server creates the JNDI name based on the service interface name and register in the RMI registry.

So the client will need to know the JNDI name to lookup the service.